# Can't run CS:GO at fullscreen (Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: steam, 18.10, fullscreen

I am unable to run CS:GO (OpenGL) at full screen natively. It ignores every time I try to change any of the screen settings. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

At the moment, it can only run windowed mode. Other games such as Rust have no issue running full screen.

Answer (score 62):

1. Open Steam
2. Go to the "Library"
3. Right-click the game which needs to be reconfigured
4. Select "Properties" from the menu
5. Click the "Set launch options..." button
6. type: -full and save

That's all.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks mate. This works. Wonder why @SkinnyCheddar hasn't selected this as the answer.

Comment: step 6 = I entered "-full screen" as -full didn't work (remove quotes)
I'm using fedora 34 and CSGO

Answer (score 4):

I just faced a similar problem. In my case, the initial window height was too big, so that part of the lower UI was cut off, including the "Apply Changes" button.

I had to set a smaller height in the game's launch options (`-h 700` for my 1366x768 screen). Aftwards I could switch to fullscreen in the video settings. After removing the launch options again, the game now starts in fullscreen mode.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Kind of an alternative and unresourceful answer, but I used the Rotation Lock (2nd icon in image) to change my screen to portrait mode, change settings accordingly, and then back to landscape.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me pressing the "Apply Changes" button had no effect. It's Gnome problem.

Solution:

1. Launch CS:GO
2. Set full schreen mode in settings, apply changes
3. Alt + F2, enter command "r" to restart Gnome session

Answer (score 0):

i use the gnome, at first i can set the fullscreen because each time i set the option to fullscreen and go back to game, it don't work.
but i find that because of the gnome windows, the apply button was covered under the screen, i click the apply button and it works!!!